# Java's String.replaceAll not working

Tags: java, string

I'm building a string that represents a polynomial. I'm trying to replace all ^1 and x^0 with "" to simplify the output using the replaceAll method. However when I run the code, it does not detect any of the target strings.

```
public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        boolean isFirst = true;
        for(Node current = head; current != null; current = current.next) {
            if(isFirst) {
                output += current.coefficient + "x^" + current.exponent;
                isFirst = false;
            }
            else if(current.coefficient < 0)
                output += " - " + current.coefficient*-1 + "x^" + current.exponent;
            else
                output += " + " + current.coefficient + "x^" + current.exponent;
        }
        output.replaceAll("x^0", "");
        output.replaceAll("^1", "");
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: That's a bold statement in your title. A bit more likely your code is wrong...

Comment: Java 101: `String`s are immutable. All methods that "modify" strings ... don't. They return a new String which is a modified copy of the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable.  You cannot alter a String.  As such, the `replace` and `replaceAll` methods return a new String.  Here try this:

```
output = output.replaceAll("x^0", "");
output = output.replaceAll("^1", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Because Strings are immutable, any *modifying* operation returns a new string. Thus, you must save and work on with the function result:

```
output = output.replace(...)
```

Also, please take a look at the definite spec for allowed patterns: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

The one point i want to call out is that a `^` at the start of a string anchors the pattern to the beginning of the string. You do not want that, so escape it: `\^`.

Anyway, you **really** want to remove the calls to `replaceAll`: `"x^1"` matches the beginning of `"x^10"`! Just don't include those substrings when you build your string.

```
double f = current.coefficient;
if(isFirst)
    isFirst = false;
else if(f < 0) {
    f = -f;
    output += " - ";
} else
    output += " + ";
output += f;
if(current.exponent == 1)
    output += "x";
else if(current.exponent != 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. If you look at the documentation, you'll see that every method that modify the content of a String returns a new one.

So you need to assign back the result of `replaceAll` to `output`.

```
output = output.replaceAll("x^0", "");
```